# Show that the equation $\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x}=2$ has no real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show that the equation $$\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x}=2$$ has no real roots.

What is the fastest approach to solve the problem? We have $$\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x}=2 \iff \sqrt{x+5}=2-\sqrt{x}$$$$D_x:\begin{cases}x+5\ge0\\x\ge0\\2-\sqrt{x}\ge0\end{cases}\iff x\in[0;4].$$$$x+5=4-4\sqrt{x}+x \text{ ...}$$ We will get that the equation has no roots.
Can I ask you what steps should I follow when I am solving a radical equation with 2 square roots?

Comment: $x$ must be $≥0$ else $\sqrt x$ is undefined.  But then $\sqrt {x+5}≥\sqrt 5>2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $x\ge 0$ and

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x}$$

is an increasing function with $f(0)= \sqrt 5 >2$ that is

$$\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x} \ge \sqrt{0+5}+\sqrt{0}= \sqrt 5>2$$

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: We haven't studied increasing or decreasing functions. How can I show that the given function is inscreasing?

Comment: @LYI Since $x\ge 0$ and $\sqrt x \ge 0$ as I wrote in the last line, we have that $\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x} \ge \sqrt{0+5}+\sqrt{0}= \sqrt 5>2$; we don't need derivative concept.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a solution, we need $x \ge 0$, and hence $\sqrt{x+5} \ge \sqrt{5}>2$.

Hence $$\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x} > 2$$

and hence the equality has no solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt{x}=2\implies$$

$$\sqrt{x+5}=2-\sqrt{x}\implies$$

$$(\sqrt{x+5})^2=(2-\sqrt{x})^2\implies$$

$$x+5=4+x-4\sqrt{x}\implies$$

$$1=-4\sqrt{x}$$

which is impossible since $1>0$ and $-4\sqrt{x}\le0$.